# How to heal your companion pet?

Tags: torchlight-2

I tried put some healing potions in pet's inventory, inside "Pet Consumables" section, but it seems pet does not use them. Is it possible to heal your companion pet when it has low health?

Comment: The cheapest way to heal your pet is with fish.  Any transformation fish will heal your pet to full HP with no cooldown as a side effect of the transformation.  If you fish at all you will have more than you need, so there is no need to waste potions on the pet when you could be using potions on yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will give your companion pet a health potion.

It is not possible to give your pet a potion when already at full health.

Giving your pet a potion will place a temporary indicator next to their health frame showing how much time is left on the currently active potion;

[image: Give your pet a potion]

It is also possible to give your pet a mana potion by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of healing your pet with potions.

First one is by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to give them the best HP potion you have, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to give them the best mana potion you have (you can also change these shortcuts in *Options>Controls*).

Second way of healing your pet is to simply put a mouse cursor over it's HP or MP bar and left-click once.